# I am trying to display the following output

Tags: for-loop

I am try to get a output like this:

```
A
BA
ABA
BABA
ABA
BA
A
```

But instead I get this:

```
AB
ABA
ABAB
ABABA
ABABAB
```

This is what i had tried, and i am totally run out of idea.

```
NSString *strA = @"A";
NSString *strB = @"B";

// Capacity does not limit the length, it's just an initial capacity
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[strA length] * 10];

for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    [result appendString:strA];
    [result appendString:strB];
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
NSString *strA = @"A";
NSString *strB = @"B";
int maxLength = 4;

NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
NSString *stringToAdd = nil;
for (int i = 0; i < maxLength * 2; i++) {
    if (i < maxLength) {
        stringToAdd = [stringToAdd isEqualToString:strA] ? strB : strA;
        [result insertString:stringToAdd atIndex:0];
    } else {
        [result deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
```

Result:

```
A  
BA  
ABA  
BABA  
ABA   
BA  
A
```